# Referencing an email address from a different sheet

Tags: vba, excel, email

I am having some trouble referencing an email address from a different sheet so I can send an email when a certain name is selected and "open" is chosen from a drop down box it will automatically send an email to that person. I have so far:

```
Sub Macro1()


Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")


On Error GoTo cleanup
For Each cell In Columns("M").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If cell.Value Like "?*@xyz.com" And _
       LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "N").Value) = "open" Then


        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = cell.Value
            .Subject = "Open Issue"
            .Body = "Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "J").Value _
                    & vbNewLine & _
                    "Issue raised: " & Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value _
                    & vbNewLine & _
                    "Regards"
            .Send
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell


cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This works if I input an email address in to column `M` manually but I am trying to have it so that when a name is selected from a drop down box in `J` it matches up the email to the name and sends it when "open" is selected from column `N`.

I have created a table with names and emails in another sheet which `M` uses `VLookup` to reference using `=VLOOKUP(J3,Team!B5:E8,4,FALSE)`. I have tried adding `HYPERLINK` in front of `VLOOKUP` but it still doesn't create a link.

I also tried creating the email address from the names using split and concatenate but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)`. Once you made column M a formula your code will now ignore all the cells that have formulas in column M.

You can adjust the `xlCellTypeConstants` to `xlCellTypeFormulas` or just get rid of `SpecialCells` altogether to include both.

Comment: Excellent! That solves it. But now I'm getting an issue "Run-time error '13' - Type Mismatch.  It is throwing up lines:

If cell.Value Like "?*@xyz.com" And _
           LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "N").Value) = "open" Then

Comment: Well, that is a different question for a different topic. However, I suspect that because you are referencing column M in your loop as a whole, it may be evaluating **EVERY ROW**, which I don't think you want. You can always debug and see which row the error occurs and then evaluate why. If you need more help with that, please post another question. Also, please mark this as answered, since the original question is solved.